# How to use re-matches with case or core.match

Tags: clojure, core.match

I am trying to implement pattern-matching in Clojure. My preference is to use `core.match` to match on a given regex pattern. I tried this:

```
(defn markdown->html [markdown-line]
  (match [markdown-line]
    [(boolean (re-matches #"#\s+\w+" markdown-line))] (str "<h1>")))
```

This does not even compile properly. I pivoted to a case conditional:

```
(defn markdown->html [markdown-line]
  (case markdown-line
    (boolean (re-matches #"#\s+\w+" markdown-line)) (str "<h1>")))
```

However, that did not give me the expected results when I invoke it with this: `(markdown->html "# Foo")`

However, this works!

```
(defn markdown->html [markdown-line]
  (if
    (boolean (re-matches #"#\s+\w+" markdown-line)) (str "<h1>")))
```

For all the tests above, I am invoking the function like so: `(markdown->html "# Foo")`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs for [`case`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case):

> The test-constants are not evaluated. They must be compile-time
> literals, and need not be quoted.

For example:

```
(case 'y
  y "y"
  c "c"
  (x z) "x or z"
  (a b) "a or b"
  "default")
```

And `clojure.core.match/match` is similar, so I'd say both are wrong tool for your problem.

If you're trying to write function for converting Github markdown to HTML, check [`clojure.string/replace`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/replace), which can help you:

```
(clojure.string/replace "# Foo bar
# Biz baz" #"#\s+([\w ]*)" (fn [[result group]] (str "<h1>" group "</h1>")))

=> "<h1>Foo bar</h1>\n<h1>Biz baz</h1>"
```

Or even better, using `$` for group:

```
(clojure.string/replace "# Foo bar
# Biz baz" #"#\s+([\w ]*)" "<h1>$1</h1>")

=> "<h1>Foo bar</h1>\n<h1>Biz baz</h1>"
```

By the way, your example can be improved like this:

```
(defn markdown->html [markdown-line]
  (when (re-matches #"#\s+\w+" markdown-line) "<h1>"))

(markdown->html "# Foo")
=> "<h1>"
```

`If` is missing *else* branch, so `when` is better; you don't have to use `boolean`, because `false` or `nil` are considered as logical false and any other value is logical true and there is no reason to wrap one string in `str`.

**EDIT:** Function for headers `<h1>` - `<h6>`:

```
(def text "# Foo bar
## Biz baz
### Foo baz
## Biz foo")

(clojure.string/replace text
                        #"(#{1,6})\s+([\w ]*)"
                        (fn [[result group1 group2]]
                          (let [tag (str "h" (count group1) ">")]
                            (str "<" tag group2 "</" tag))))

=> "<h1>Foo bar</h1>\n<h2>Biz baz</h2>\n<h3>Foo baz</h3>\n<h2>Biz foo</h2>"
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin -

However, I also want to cater for `#{n}`. I tried `#{2}\s+([\w ]*)` but it did not seem to match `## text`. Do you have an idea how to craft a `cond` to achieve that?

Comment: @tweeterist I'd do that without `cond`, using two groups in regex. See edit.